GNUcash - How to actually edit rules in the Import Match Editor
The import match editor only shows (many faulty) import rules every time after i imported lines. I only see a way to select and delete lines.
I would like to actually EDIT lines, so that I can use e.g. the account number of the other party to auto match. How can I edit import rules?
Examples:

I now have a line that says Match string: "Lidl sagt danke" This is mapped to account name "Food". I want the supermarket name "Lidl" to match with that account, no matter where this particular supermarket was (Obviously this one had been in Germany).

I now have the Bayesian Match string "date/time" matched to a certain account. If I can find out which transaction was used to generate this very annoying match, I can edit the string to a better, more error safe, match string.

I like to add exclusion strings that should never be used to match anything. As new strings like this are generated each time!: "Name:", "Account nr:", "description:", "JD" (my initials), "Mr.", "Smith" (my last name), "15-08-2024" or "22:58:13" (the specific date or time of a transaction).
It seems very clear that the import matcher needs some work to exclude certain strings as well, espescially the ones that are on every bank transaction.



what software is this related to?

And is there a reason you aren't asking its support group, where you will find experts in its use? Even if there is such a community on Stack Exchange, this personal finance discussion isn't it.

@kesham I was under the impression this group is for GNUcash. Got redirected here. If not, please point me to the right page.

I've not used the GnuCash Import Match Editor, but I think that you are correct about its limitations - it lets you delete incorrect match strings but does not allow you to modify existing matches or create new ones.  It appears that the way to generate new correct match strings is by actually importing new transactions through the File/Import processes.
So my suggestion for cleaning up your Import transaction matches is to firstly Delete any incorrect matches through the Import Match Editor then keep importing your live data and specifying the correct matches for GnuCash to remember through the standard Import process.
I don't recommend the following, but I'll include it in case you like to live dangerously.
GnuCash stores a lot of information about processes, preferences, saved reports, and more as text files in various locations.  If you select Help/About GnuCash will display those locations.  One of those files in one of those locations will contain the various match strings that you want to edit.
For example, on my Windows machine there's a file C:\Users\greg\AppData\Roaming\GnuCash\qif-accounts-map.  It's organised in a particular format that I don't know the protocol for, and it appears to have data that could be relevant to your query.  Right at the top of the data it says
;;; qif-accounts-map
;;; Automatically generated by GnuCash. DO NOT EDIT.
;;; (Unless you really, really want to.)
;;; Map QIF accounts to GnuCash accounts 

You have been warned.
I don't know if this is THE file that contains the transaction matching data that you want to edit, or if the data is in another file.  I don't know your level of competence in editing data while still maintaining the required data format.
The GnuCash developers have recommended that you DON'T edit this data directly, but hey - it's your GnuCash system now.  I just strongly recommend that you keep good backups of uncorrupted files before you start to dabble.
